# EC2 Folder Permissions on Amazon AWS

Tags: amazon-ec2, permissions

This is first time I am setting up my Wordpress blog myself. Usually, I would purchase a GoDaddy account and be done with it. Now, I have bought a Amazon AWS and setting up on EC2. I have finished my setup. My only question is what should be the folder permissions? 
I have read that folder permissions are important as they are one of the reasons sites get hacked. So what permission should I set?

My file location are as follows: Currently html, wordpress and all files below is set with 777

/var/www/html/wordpress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KD - Good question. You should set permission 755 for all directories. Make sure that never set 777 permission for any folder/files.

Also best thing is you set **755** for all word-press folders and **644** for all files.

More details of permission :

777 – all can read, write and execute

644 - owner can modify file and everyone can read file